# problem in sublime text 3 with spanish characters

Tags: keyboard-layout, sublime-text, internationalization

I've just installed Ubuntu 14.10 and configured US international keyboard with dead keys.

In every app, when I type the ' char followed by a, I get a nice á char.

But in sublime-text-3 I get ´a...

And also the compose key is not working either...

Is there anybody else having the same problem?

Comment: Have you tried inserting the char through it's unicode code? Like `00e9` for é? You do it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and then you let them all go and start typing in the code. Does it enter character normally then?

Comment: I tried it but I only get a '00e9' string.. I guess I must be doing something wrong...

Comment: Finally I solved it thanks to this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28918768/47633